# Why am I getting the error with max function when I use long long int and int as arguments

Tags: c++

I'am new to C++ just had this unexpected error with using `max` function, where I pass arguments of type long long and int

When i pass `(int,int)` as arguments or `(long long,long long)` it works fine but not with `(long long,int)`

```
ll painter(int board[],int n,int k)
{

 ll  s = 0,total_min;
 ll ans;

 for(ll i = 0;i < n;i++)
   { total_min += board[i];
       s = max(s,board[i]);

}
```

This is the error showing

```
prog.cpp:39:25: error: no matching function for call to 'max(int&, long long int&)
        s =max(s,board[i]);"
```

Comment: Because the template function `max` expects the two arguments to be of the same type, and because the usual arithmetic conversion rules don't apply when calling a template function. Just add a cast, and don't use typedefs like `ll`.

Comment: Aside: You could instead write this as `ll s = *std::max_element(board, board+n); ll total_min = std::accumulate(board, board+n, 0);` (assuming `n` is never 0). Another aside: you don't initialise `total_min`, so your program has undefined behaviour

Comment: This feature is confusing to novices because the normal relational operators (>, < etc.) perform conversions but the closely related (in meaning) `std::max()` does not.

Answer (score 4):

Because `std::max` is a function template whose signature is, for example,

```
template< class T > 
const T& max( const T& a, const T& b );
```

complete list at: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max

Now, when instantiating the template you give two different types but the templates only wants one. You have to explicitly specify the template argument, like in this example:

```
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    int a{5};
    long long int b{55};
    return std::max<long long int>(a, b);
}
```

As noted in the comments (user John), you can also cast one of the two, for example you can cast the `int` to `long long`

Answer (score 2):

The signature of [`std::max`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) is:

```cpp
template< class T > 
constexpr const T& max( const T& a, const T& b );
```

So `max` expects both arguments to be of the same type, if they are not fo the same type then you explicitly need set the template argument:

```
std::max<long long int>(s, board[i])
```

Or you need to ensure that both arguments are of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

std::max() accepts parameters that are of the same type.
If you want to compare two variables that are not of the same you will have to cast one into another.
In this case i suggest casting int into long long int so you don't lose anything.